# Поменяйте текст на кнопках и возле вопроса

Tags: дефект, локализация

Кнопка "Проверьте ваш вопрос". Это звучит настолько тупо и не по-русски. Ведь при нажатии на эту кнопку пользователь проверяет не чужой, а свой вопрос (система тоже - проверяет вопрос ЭТОГО пользователя) поэтому логичнее написать "Проверьте свой вопрос".

Кнопка "Задайте ваш вопрос". Опять же, я не обращаюсь к кому-то, чтобы он задал СВОЙ, а не МОЙ вопрос. Поэтому, тут должно быть, например, "Опубликовать вопрос", т.е. сделать так, чтобы его увидели другие люди.

На картинке есть надпись "3 показа", а должна быть "3 просмотра", т.к. тут никто ни кому ничего не показывает. Здесь ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛИ ПРОСМАТРИВАЮТ вопрос!

[image: ПОКАЗЫ]

Comment: _тут никто ни кому ничего не показывает_ - почему? Сайт показывает вопрос.

Comment: и при этом сайт совершенно точно знает, сколько раз вопрос был показан, но не знает, сколько раз его просмотрели.

Comment: Как по мне разница не особо существенная. Я насчёт показов я согласен, показ звучит больше как что-то типа демонстрация / презентация, а не просмотр.

Comment: слово "просмотр" просто не влезет в этот "новый модный дизайн". Поэтому подобрали "синоним".

Comment: Там полно места

Comment: я понимаю, что Вы недавно здесь и не видели старого дизайна этого блока с голосами/"показами". Тут проблема сильно глубже и эта строка погоды не делает.

Comment: Ну лично у меня от такой локализации глаза страдают, хотя, может, это моя проблема. Открыл сайт в веб-архиве, дабы посмотреть на старый дизайн, и скажу честно, что новый мне больше вкатывает.

Comment: для меня русский не родной, я его знаю очень плохо и мне очень сложно судить о корректности локализации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Кнопка "Проверьте ваш вопрос".

Нет, именно сам пользователь проверяет свой вопрос. При её нажатии вопрос скроллистя к началу, предполагается, что пользователь его перечитывает и нажимает кнопку ещё раз.

> Кнопка "Задайте ваш вопрос".

Наверное, логично.

> надпись "3 показа", а должна быть "3 просмотра"

Да, потому что при открытии вопроса оно же называется порсмотрами.

Comment: Но как бы, нажав на Проверьте ваш вопрос, вверху показывается плашка "НАША СИСТЕМА проверила вопрос..."

Comment: Хотя, там есть и то, и то. Только тогда надо "Проверьте свой вопрос".

Comment: @HumanNo1, согласен, "свой" лучше, чем "ваш".